# Which is the lowest Android API for which Rupee Unicode U+20B9 works?

Tags: android, unicode

I want to include Rupee U+20B9 unicode to display Rupee symbol in the app, But I'm not sure if the unicode will be displayed by all version of Android ( my app's minSDK is 14)

Rupee symbol came out in [July 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_rupee_sign), API 14 came out in [Oct 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history). Also Android [platform seems to have unicode support before 2011](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/commits/9fc2cd20a615a03b0375769939ba0dc1a946f4ac/include/utils/Unicode.h)

Would it be safe to assume that API 14 and higher can display Rupee symbol using U+20B9 unicode in TextView ?

Comment: Load up a simulator and find out I'd say

Comment: Actually I didn't find Android 4.0 for Genymotion. And on Mac OSX  I'm not able to run Android Emulator with API 14. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I personally wouldn't worry about it. Nobody uses api 14 anyway

Comment: Just use Android AVDs from SDK. To load any api.

Comment: Ok Update: seems to be working on AVD for API 14.